# How this memory leak caused?

Tags: javascript, dom, memory-management

**UPDATE:** I guess I have to assume my understanding is right(probably, but if you have a better explanation, **please let me know**), it just needs to take a little more time for Chrome to GC the detached DOMs(I do not know how long it should take, a lot of times it does not GC at all for pretty long time)

[image]

---

All:

I am pretty new to Javascript memory management,when I read Google Chrome(Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (32-bit) Windows 7) Devtool tutorial, there is one example:

[Discover detached DOM tree memory leaks with Heap Snapshots](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/)

```
var detachedNodes;

function create() {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  detachedNodes = ul;
}

document.getElementById('create').addEventListener('click', create);
```

I guess the reason is I have not understood how DOM works in memory.

My thought is: each time of clicking, an execution context built for `create`, a local var ul entered there referring the UL object generated in heap, then 10 li generated in heap, and connected with UL object, then the UL object gets referenced by detachedNode. **And I thought: after the create()call, the reference between detachedNode and previous UL object will be broken(generated during the call to create() before this click), and document.createElement only creates but not appends, so that UL object should be GCed.**

I wonder why that UL object in heap can not be GCed?

[image]

Comment: which chrome version you are using? I can not reproduce the whole case on chrome 66

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher Thanks for interest. Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (32-bit) Windows 7. BTW, which case is more like on your side: keep increasing, or a drop sometime?

Comment: could you please try again on chrome 66 , I am pretty interested in this question

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher I will try to find ver 66 chrome, currently I am not allowed to do that.

Comment: NP , I will be follwoing any updates on this

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher I have contacted the author at Google, waiting for reply

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher I tried on Ubuntu AMD 64bit Chrome 66, really hard to make the green node line drop, but the heap does drop a lil bit.

Answer (score 3):

If I click the button once, it creates that a DOM tree under that `ul` element, and then assigns it to the global `detachedNodes` variable (i.e. `detachedNodes` will reference that object in memory).

If I click it again, it'll assign a new `ul` element tree to `detachedNodes`, but now the old `ul` element won't be referenced any more. In this case, the `ul` tree from the first click will be garbage collected since no more references to it exist.

So to answer your question: yes, that first node can be garbage collected. The Google article you linked to doesn't seem to imply otherwise; it doesn't address clicking the button more than once at all from what I see.

Comment: Hi, I wrote that article (or just updated an old one, can't remember). Kuan's analysis (in the question) and John's answer seem correct. We can improve the sample by changing `detachedNodes` to an array, and then pushing each new `ul` to the array. That will make the detached DOM tree grow. Added a bug on myself to improve the page: https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/issues/6104